# What is wrong with my guess game?

Tags: python, function, user-input

I tried to make a simple "guess game", but all it does is asks for an input and that's it.

Here is my code:

```
import random

def guess():
    if a == b:
        print "Correct!"
        n = input("Press 0 to quit or 1 to try again.")
        if n == 0:
            print ""
        if n == 1:
            return guess
    else:
        print "Wrong! "
        n = input("Press 0 to quit or 1 to try again.")
        if n == 0:
            print ""
        if n == 1:
            return guess

a = random.randint(1,2000)
b = input("Guess a number between 1 and 2000 ")
```

Comment: You define the `guess` method but not call it.

Comment: First of all, don't use `input` in Python 2 (use `raw_input`). Secondly, you never call `guess()`.

Comment: Like @Wooble said, avoid using `input` as that's equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, which means it will execute arbitrary Python code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not calling the `guess` function. You should add at the end:

```
guess(a, b)
```

and you should modify the `guess` function as follows:

```
def guess(a, b):
    # your code here
```

This is necessary because you need to pass the values `a` and `b` to your `guess` function. Otherwise, `a` and `b` inside the `guess` function have no value (they are just undefined local variables) and Python would not know what to do.

By doing the above, you can at least check if you guessed correctly or not. But you'll need to modify the code a bit more if you want to repeat the guessing.

---

As an example, here is an updated version of the guess game that does work:

```
import random

def guess(a):
    b = raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 2000 ")
    if a == b:
        print "Correct!"
    else:
        print "Wrong! "
        n = raw_input("Press 0 to quit or 1 to try again.")
        if n == "0":
            print ""
        if n == "1":
            guess(a)

a = random.randint(1, 2000)
guess(a)
```

The function `guess` now takes one integer: the integer that needs to be guessed. Inside the function, we ask the user for an integer and we store it in `b`. We then tell the user whether the guess is correct or not. If the guess is correct then the function `guess` just ends.

If the guess was wrong then we give the user to chance to try again if they want to. Note that we are now checking `if n == "0":` instead of `if n == 0:` because `n` is a string, not an integer. If the user typed `1` then we call `guess` again with the integer to be guessed (`a`) and the whole thing starts again.

Comment: Except this won't fix everything else wrong with the program, like `guess` trying to return itself.

Comment: @Wooble: That is true. But fixing the code has to start somewhere.

Comment: Consider including something about using [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) rather than input - it's much safer because it doesn't include an `eval` call!